# Does parentheses directly after a class name create a new instance?

Tags: c++, constructor

```
// in a.h
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<double> Array;
class A
{
    public:
          A(int n);
    private:
          Array m;
};

//in a.cpp
#include "a.h"
A::A(int n)
{
    m = Array(n, 0.0);
}
```

I want to initialize m in the constructor of A. Is the expression of parentheses with some parameters directly after the class name (`std::vector<double>`) legal?

And what's is the difference between 
     `Array m(n,0.0)`
     and 
     `m=Array(n,0.0)`?

Comment: Please note that the preferred way to do this is to use an initializer list: `A::A(int n) : m(n, 0.0) { }` This directly invokes the constructor for the m member without any copying or overhead. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Comment: Is that a new C++ standard?

Comment: @black No, it isn’t.

Answer (score 7):

1. Yes it is legal. `ClassName()` calls the constructor of that class.

   *Note: Technically, a constructor doesn't have a name, so it can't be found during the name lookup, so `ClassName()` is really an explicit type conversion using the functional notation which _results in_ calling the constructor (as per c++ standard 12.1.2).*
2. `Array m(n,0.0)` creates a variable `m` of a class `Array` by calling `Array`'s constructor that accepts 3 parameters.

   `MyClass m = Array(n,0.0)` creates an unnamed variable of a class `Array` by calling `Array`'s constructor with 3 parameters, and then copies that unnamed variable into `m`, but most likely the compiler will optimise that thanks to [copy elision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision). However, if you changed that to `MyClass m; m = Array(n,0.0)`, a constructor followed by assignment operator will be called.

Comment: @TartanLlama, I didn't want to overcomplicate the answer, but I added that as a note. As for the copy elision, well I tested it and it does elide, but I've edited the answer a bit to avoid misunderstanding